# How to compare Strings in MyBatis 3 in XML <if test> ignoring the case

Tags: xml, mybatis

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281269/how-to-compare-strings-in-mybatis-3-with-if-statement-dynamic-sql) states

```
<if test="sortBy == 'col1' ">
     ...
</if>
```

does only compare String by case. Is there a way like equalsIgnoreCase in MyBatis XML Mapper?

Inelegantly one could

```
<if test="sortBy == 'col1' or sortBy == 'COL1' ">
   ...
</if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code will work, just change the *test* attribute double quotes by simple quotes, or escape them:

```
<if test='"col1".equalsIgnoreCase(sortBy)'> 
 ...
</if>
```